# Set up database for integration tests with TestMain across multiple packages

Tags: go, testing

I am trying to write database integration tests in my go application for my repositories files.

My idea was to leverage the `TestMain` function to do the database bootstrap before the tests are run.

Example:

**test/integration/integration_test.go**

```golang
// +build integrationdb

package main

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {

    flag.Parse()
    
    // setup database
    setupDB()

    // run tests
    os.Exit(m.Run())
}
```

Because this is global to all my integration tests I have placed this code in the test/integration package.

Then in each module/package of my application, together with my repository.go code, I have a `repository_test.go` with my test code:

```golang
// +build integrationdb

package todo_test

import (
    "github.com/brpaz/go-api-sample/internal/todo"
    "github.com/brpaz/go-api-sample/test/testutil"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "testing"
)


func TestPgRepository_CreateTodo(t *testing.T) {
    db, err := testutil.GetTestDBConnection()

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    repo := todo.NewPgRepository(db)

    err = repo.CreateTodo(todo.CreateTodo{
        Description: "some-todo",
    })

    assert.Nil(t, err)
}
```

The setup works fine, the issue is that when running the tests, it says "**testing: warning: no tests to run**" and the tests are still executed, without running the `TestMain` function.

It seems that the `TestMain` function is per package? Is that true? Any workarounds?

I could put all the test files into a unique and separate package (I do that for higher-level tests like acceptance and smoke tests), but since I am testing each repository individually, It doesn't differ that much from a unit test, so I think it makes sense to keep then together with the code.

I guess I could create a `TestMain` per package and have some global variable in my global `testutils` package that kept if the database was initialized and run the setup if not set. Not really a fan of globals.

The other alternative I see is to move the setup code outside of the test logic. I prefer it to keep tightly integrated with Go as it makes it easier to defer cleanup functions for example, after the tests run.

Maybe I can create my own "integration test runner" command, that would run the setup code and then call "go test" programmatically?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Each package is always tested independently. If you want coordination between the package tests, then you need to do that on your own.

Comment: Maybe you could do the setup in a `init()` function of the `testutil` package and then you don't need to rely on the `TestMain`s.

Comment: Needing this implies there may be some underlying design issues; in theory, you'd have one package which interfaces with the database, which you would integration test with the database, then other packages would only access the database via that package, and could mock it out in their own tests; since the repository package's tests have already proven it works with the database, database integration tests in other packages would seem redundant.

Comment: well the database connection logic is handled in a single package. but each of my packages has their respective repositories and queries. For example, users package there is an UsersRepository interface that is responsible for doing queries related to users. The packages are independent but before running each of them a database instance with a test database must be running. That´s the tricky part. I could have a script outside of go to  do that bootstrap and then running the tests but would prefer it to be integrated with go test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tests of each package can be run independently as they should. The only missing link was the bootstrap and teardown of the test database.

I decided to create a command in my application that will bootstrap the tests database and then running the "go test".

I could have this bootstrap logic separated, let´s say in a bash script, but I feel this way makes it easier.

Here is the code I ended up with for reference:

**test/integration/db/main.go**

```golang
func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    log.Println("Setup DB")

    // setupDB creates a new test database and runs the application migrations before the tests start.
    setupDB()

    log.Println("Running Tests")

    // calls go test to execute the tests.
    runTests()

   // delete the test database.
   teardownDB()
}

func runTests() {
    // TODO this flags can be passed from the original command instead.
    cmd := exec.Command("go", "test", "-v", "--tags", "integrationdb", "-p", "1", "./...")
    cmd.Env = os.Environ()

    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```